# loging php page not redirecting

Tags: authentication

I have a login.php page created with Dreamweaver CS4.
After inputting username and password in the form the page reloads itself not redirecting to desire location.
URL for existing website: http://www.decoraflooringstore.com
login page opens after clicking on client login
Below is the php code:
Thanks for any input

```
<?php require_once('Connections/test.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
   $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
     case "text":
         $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
         break;    
      case "long":
      case "int":
         $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
         break;
      case "double":
         $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
         break;
      case "date":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
        break;
      case "defined":
         $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
         break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT `user`.`user name`, `user`.password FROM `user`";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $test) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
   session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
   $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
   $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
   $password=$_POST['username'];
   $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
   $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "success login.php";
   $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "failed login.php";
   $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
   mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);

   $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT `user name`, password FROM `user` WHERE `user     name`=%s AND password=%s",
      GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

   $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $test) or die(mysql_error());
   $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
   if ($loginFoundUser) {
      $loginStrGroup = "";

      //declare two session variables and assign them
      $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
      $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;         

      if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
         $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];   
      }
      header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
   }
   else {
      header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
   }
}
?>
<table width="500" border="0" align="center">
   <tr>
      <td><table width="400" border="0" align="center">
         <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>">
               <label>
                 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
              </label>
            </form></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Password</td>
             <td><form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
                <label>
                   <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
                </label>
             </form></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td><form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
               <label>
                <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
               </label>
             </form></td>
          </tr>
       </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: You don't need to open and close a php tag every function yo have(THAT IS NASTY)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to redirect, you must avoid sending previous contents. Otherwise you will receive the message "headers already sent".

The command session_start() will send headers, not allowing further redirection.

Avoid also having multiple opening and closing php tags. You are sending newline chars between the closing tags and the next opening tags. This will also cause headers to be sent, not allowing the redirection to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

use isset function for checking user name and password .and i in the conditional statement
if passsword is right 
header("location:index.php");
else
header("location:something.php");
what it does it if your information is valid it will redirect to index.php and if not valid it will redirect to something.php